# Select weekly average of user usage, only for some users (mysql)

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, average, union

I have 2 tables, and I want to show a weekly TOTAL average of data usage for users who started using the application 10 weeks ago. (in that week)

Table 1 is called "users"

```
user_id user_name   user_date
1           a       2020-05-01
2           b       2020-05-03
3           c       2020-06-01
4           d       2020-06-06
5           e       2020-06-09
```

Table 2 is called "data_tbl"

```
data_id     user_id     date_used   data_used
1               1       2020-05-09      7
2               1       2020-05-09      12
3               2       2020-05-12      100
4               2       2020-05-20      177 
5               1       2020-05-21      78
6               2       2020-05-29      33  
7               1       2020-06-01      44
8               2       2020-06-01      123
9               1       2020-06-03      62
```

Consider 10 weeks ago is between 2020-05-01 and 2020-05-08

So the 2 users we are interested in in that case is user_id 1 and 2 (a and b)

We consider first week from 05-01 to 05-08

Second week from 2020-05-08 to 2020-05-15

Third week from 2020-05-15 to 2020-05-22

Forth week from 2020-05-22 to 2020-05-29 and so on

```
For week 1 we would have average usage = 0
For week 2 we would have average usage (7+12+100)/3=39
For week 3 we would have average usage (177+78)/2=127
For week 4 we would have average usage 33
For week 5 we would have average usage (44+123+62)/3=76
```

I really don't know how to start, if I should do a join, or a select in select with average.
I tested something like: (but no success)

```
SELECT AVG(data_used),
FROM data_tbl
LEFT JOIN users ON data_tbl.user_id=users.user_id
WHERE users.user_date>= "2020-05-01" AND users.user_date<="2020-05-08"
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this easily with [YEARWEEK()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_yearweek.asp) function

However what you want to achieve is not totally clear for me because the results you want don't really match your data.

Example:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(SYSDATE()) AS Actual_Week, 
       YEARWEEK(user_date) User_Date_Week, 
       YEARWEEK(SYSDATE()) - YEARWEEK(user_date) AS diff_weeks  , 
       u.*  
FROM users u
```

Returns

```
Actual_Week   User_Date_Week    diff_weeks  user_id     user_name   user_date
202029        202017             12         1           a           2020-05-01
202029        202018             11         2           b           2020-05-03
202029        202022             7          3           c           2020-06-01
202029        202022             7          4           d           2020-06-06
202029        202023             6          5           e           2020-06-09
```

So you can see that user 1 is 12 weeks ago, and user 2 is 11 week ago. And you assume they are 10 weeks ago, which is incorrect. Sames goes with your date_used in  data_tbl.

So I'll just put you on the right path, it should then be easy to adapt following your needs...

Do something like this

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(d.date_used), AVG(data_used)
FROM users u
INNER JOIN data_tbl d ON u.user_id = d.user_id  
WHERE (YEARWEEK(SYSDATE()) - YEARWEEK(u.user_date)) BETWEEN 11 AND 12  
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(d.date_used)
```

Returns

```
YEARWEEK(d.date_used)   AVG(data_used)
202018                  9.5
202019                  100
202020                  127.5
202021                  33
202022                  76.3333
```

You can see that the numbers you expect are there, but that they are others. And this result seems correct to me, the results in your question were wrong.

Notice that to get the results for user 1 and 2, I specified

```
 WHERE (YEARWEEK(SYSDATE()) - YEARWEEK(u.user_date)) BETWEEN 11 AND 12
```

If you want the user of 10 weeks ago, just do

```
 WHERE (YEARWEEK(SYSDATE()) - YEARWEEK(u.user_date)) = 10
```

And to conclude :

1. you might want to change the **mode** of YEARWEEK(), if the weeks should start on Monday, Sunday, or other options. Modes are well described [here](https://database.guide/yearweek-examples-mysql/), with plenty of examples
2. If you also want the weeks without data in your results (so always 0), you have to use a Calendar table. There are plenty of examples on SO.